# Extracing elements from a nested list based on elements of another nested list

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

I have two nested lists - one containing userids and their individual location and the second nested list containing product first element and list of userid who have purchased the products. I need to find the unique locations of purchasers for each product.

I am able to get the results by using nested for loops. However, i wanted to the same by list comprehension. i don't want to use dataframes or sql commands.

```
users=([1,'MX'],[2,'EN'],[3,'US'],[4,'FR'],[5,'US'],[6,'EN'],[7,'MX'])

    prod=[
        (1005,[5]),
        (1004,[2,4,1]),
        (1003,[3,5]),
        (1002,[7,5,2]),
        (1001,[6,5,1])
        ]
    for p in prod:
        prod_loc=[]
        for u in p[1]:
          for uloc in users:

            if u==uloc[0]:
                if uloc[1] not in prod_loc:
                    prod_loc.append(uloc[1])

            else:
                continue
        print (p[0],prod_loc)
```

Comment: expected output please

Answer (score 2):

You would like first to create a dictionary of users, and then you can use nested list comprehension to match them in a single code line

```py
dict_users = {x[0]: x[1] for x in users}
prod = [[x[0], [dict_users[y] for y in x[1]]] for x in prod]
```

As you can see, you are iterating over each element in prod

```py
[_ for x in prod]
```

With a list that match the elements of dict_users for each element in the list

```py
[x[0], [dict_users[y] for y in x[1]]]
```

Comment: you can do `dict_users = dict(users)` in the first line

Comment: Sure, but i prefer to use the function to notice what we are doing :)

Answer (score 1):

`[(e[0], list(set(dict(users)[r] for r in e[1]))) for e in prod]`

Explained:

```
[
    ( # Tuple
        e[0], # Prod name
        list( # Convert to list
            set( # Set of unique elements
                dict(users)[r] # Get region of user
                for r in e[1] # For each user in the list of prod
            )
        )
    )
    for e in prod # For each prod
]
```

Result:

```
[(1005, ['US']),
 (1004, ['MX', 'EN', 'FR']),
 (1003, ['US']),
 (1002, ['MX', 'EN', 'US']),
 (1001, ['US', 'EN', 'MX'])]
```

P.S. It can be better to move `dict(users)` to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

With `defaultdict` and `set` objects (*"to find the unique locations of purchasers for each product"*):

```
from collections import defaultdict
...

users_dict, result = dict(users), defaultdict(set)

for prod_id, user_ids in prod:
    result[prod_id].update(set(users_dict.get(u_id) for u_id in user_ids))

result = list(result.items())
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[(1005, {'US'}), (1004, {'EN', 'MX', 'FR'}), (1003, {'US'}), (1002, {'US', 'MX', 'EN'}), (1001, {'EN', 'US', 'MX'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
from itertools import groupby

users=([1,'MX'],[2,'EN'],[3,'US'],[4,'FR'],[5,'US'],[6,'EN'],[7,'MX'])

prod=[
    (1005,[5]),
    (1004,[2,4,1]),
    (1003,[3,5]),
    (1002,[7,5,2]),
    (1001,[6,5,1])
    ]

temp = [(p[0],u[1]) for p in prod for u in users if u[0] in p[1]]
result = []

for id, locations in groupby(temp, key=lambda x: x[0]):
            result.append((id, {x[1] for x in locations}))
```

The ouput is:

```
[(1005, {'US'}), (1004, {'MX', 'FR', 'EN'}), (1003, {'US'}), (1002, {'EN', 'US', 'MX'}), (1001, {'MX', 'US', 'EN'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and map.

```py
list(map(lambda x: (x[0], set([ul[1] for u in x[1] for ul in users if ul[0]==u])), prod))
```

Output

```
[(1005, {'US'}),
 (1004, {'EN', 'FR', 'MX'}),
 (1003, {'US'}),
 (1002, {'EN', 'MX', 'US'}),
 (1001, {'EN', 'MX', 'US'})]
```

To get a dictionary simply pass the output of `map` to `dict`.

```py
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], set([ul[1] for u in x[1] for ul in users if ul[0]==u])), prod))
```

Output

```
{1005: {'US'},
 1004: {'EN', 'FR', 'MX'},
 1003: {'US'},
 1002: {'EN', 'MX', 'US'},
 1001: {'EN', 'MX', 'US'}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to have unique locations. eg. for prod 1003, only one 'US' is required

Comment: Made change: pass result of list comprehension to `set`.

Answer (score 0):

### Single line solution using `list comprehension`

> [(z[0], [j[1] for i in z[1] for j in users if j[0] == i]) for z in prod]

```
    # How to solve this kinda problem step by step:
    # First assume you have only one element in prod --> (1004, [2, 4, 1]).
    # Now write a list comprehension to replace the [2, 4, 1] with ['MX', 'EN', 'FR'], this can be done using 2 for loops as below:
    aa = [2, 4, 1]
    print ([j[1] for i in aa for j in users if j[0] == i])

    # Now perform above logic for the entire prod data using for loop and store desired result:
    print ([(z[0], [j[1] for i in z[1] for j in users if j[0] == i]) for z in prod])
```

I hope this counts. :)